# Magento 2 How to hide price of product and add to cart button and Show a custom Link if not logged in

Tags: magento2, product, price, addtocart

How to Hide the Price of the product and also add to cart button if the user is not logged in and want to give a link in place of Add to cart button to Login.

Comment: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-hide-prices-and-add-to-cart-button-for-non-logged-in-visitors.html try this....

Comment: Hello @asad please refer this "https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask" link to ask good question we need your do's & try's and where you stuck so according it community member helps you.

Comment: @Ajithkumar this is for Magento 1...

Comment: @Himanshu Sir I'm new next time I'll try my best

Comment: @Asad you want to hide product price throughout the website if user not logged in right??

Comment: @Ajithkumar Yes! and also want to hide 'add to cart' button if not logged in